# How to get the blob-name of a @BlobInput?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

Consider the Azure Function as shown below, that gets triggered upon blob upload. I'd like to scale that image and write it back to another blob container. And finally, send a message to a service bus topic containing the status and a link to the scaled image.

Currently, I am just generating a random blob name.

How can I get the ***name*** of the blob read by the `@BlobInput`? The source name is encoded in the `EventSchema`, however, I don't know how to reuse a parsed/substringed version of `{data.url}` as a parameter to `@BlobOutput(..., path = "xxx") ...`.

```
public class ImageScaleFunction {

    @FunctionName("ImageScaleFunction")
    @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
    public void run(
            @EventGridTrigger(name = "eventGridEvent") EventSchema event,
            @BlobInput(name = "input", dataType = "binary", path = "{data.url}") byte[] blobInput,
            @BlobOutput(name = "output", dataType = "binary", path = "image-output/{rand-guid}.jpg")  OutputBinding<byte[]> blobOutput,
            @ServiceBusQueueOutput(name = "message", dataType = "string", queueName = "my-cool-queue", connection = "AzureServiceBusConnection") OutputBinding<String> message,
            final ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {

    // .. 
    
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema

```
public class EventSchema {
    public String id;
    public String eventType;
    public String subject;
    public Date eventTime;
    public String dataVersion;
    public String topic;
    public String metadataVersion;
    public Map<String, Object> data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can [fetch trigger metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption#metadata), there is no way to get similar data from an input binding.

You would either have to directly use the Storage SDK for the output, or forward the Event Grid event as a queue message which has your own payload schema and use a second function which processes the queue message to bind to the filename present in the message payload.